# React. In class component Return doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, class, components

I am new with react. Just started today. I am on the Class Component Subject when I write return it is supossed to return the htm but it doesn´t. Anyone know my errors?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I´m going to send the picture

[image]

Comment: The code snippet and the right image are incomplete. You haven't yet written what you want it to return. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: You need to add some code inside the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<div>Hello</div>` (or whatever you want to be there) on line 8

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Is a great example of a class based component boilerplate. However, you're saying return... Well... nothing. Without going into the intricacies of JSX, Babel, etc, the basic answer is that your class isn't returning anything, so there's nothing to show.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Oh, hi there!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Will result in the DOM rendering a div and a h1 with the text "Oh, hi there!".

It's essentially the same as writing a standard function and returning a value, but you're returning JSX!
An example if you were writing a standard JS function with these same problems would be:

```
const sumNumbers = (firstNumber, secondNumber) => { 
  let answer = firstNumber + secondNumber
  return;
}

console.log(sumNumbers(1, 2));
// undefined
```

Versus

```
const sumNumbers = (firstNumber, secondNumber) => { 
  return firstNumber + secondNumber;
}

console.log(sumNumbers(1, 2));
// 3
```